# Get cart item product attribute not assigned to variations in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I have 2 attributes (DiscQuantity, Discount) for all products that have value that I'm going to use later  in cart and checkout page to apply discount, these attributes are not assigned for variations
I want to get the value in these attributes to pass it to a script that implement the discount
The problem is when run this script

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'progressive_discount_by_item_quantity', 10, 1 );
function progressive_discount_by_item_quantity( $cart_obj ) {

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;
foreach( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $item_values ){
$_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $item_values['data'] );
$foobar = $_product->get_attribute( 'DiscQuantity' );
?><pre><?php var_dump( $foobar ); ?></pre><?php
}}
 //rest of Discount code
```

var_dump shows this result
**string(0) ""**

I proceed to debug and printed _product in var_dumb it shows only the attributes that are assigned for variations and the two attributes that i need are missing

```
["attributes"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["pa_size"]=>
      string(1) "s"
      ["pa_color"]=>
      string(3) "red"
      ["pa_fasttrack"]=>
      string(6) "normal"
    }
```

my question is how can get these 2 attributes value without assigning them to variations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a cart item is a product variation, you will get the parent variable product object as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'progressive_discount_by_item_quantity', 10, 1 );
function progressive_discount_by_item_quantity( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // Get the variale product Object when it's a product variation
        $product = $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ? wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']) : $cart_item['data'];
        
        $disc_qty = $product->get_attribute( 'DiscQuantity' );
        
        echo '<pre class="custom">'. print_r( $disc_qty, true ) . '</pre>';
    }
}
```

This time you will not get an empty value.

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks alot @LoicTheAztec